# Back propagation for cross entropy loss function with softmax mathematical partial derivatives

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I am trying to solve the math for back propagation algorithm using cross-entropy cost/loss function and softmax activation function in output layer.

The network architecture for 3-class classification is as follows:

The input layer has two input neurons (i1 and i2)

There is a single hidden layer having 3 neurons (h1, h2 and h3)

The output layer has 3 output neurons (o1, o2 and o3). These output scores or logits are fed into the softmax function which then outputs the probabilities (S1, S2 and S3).

I am attaching a hand sketched image for a visual representation of the neural network.

[image: Neural Network Architecture]

w1 is the weight from hidden neuron h1 to output neuron o1.

And, w13 is the weight from input neuron i1 to hidden neuron h1.

The mathematical partial derivative equations which I have come up with are:

[image]

OR:

[image]

Where, S_1 refers to softmax output for 1st class, out_o1 refers to output of first output neuron and net_01 refers to network input for output neuron o1.

Is my mathematical partial derivative equations correct?

Also, I wish to compute the partial derivative of:

[image]

What should the equations look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add pictures of your latex equations? It would make them easier to read.

Comment: I have added pictures and removed the latex codes